# Await inside createreadStream function not pushing the fetched data into an arrray, Instead goes to next iteration and again fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv, async-await

Here I am trying to call every row in a csv file and inside that ".on" we can access every row so I am fetching some data there and then pushing that fetched data into the an array but I see that it call the fetch and then directly goes to next row instead of pushing the data into the array. Any idea on why it is not pushing the data into the array and then go to the next iteration?

```
var dataArray = [];

fs.createReadStream('./data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', async function (row) {
    let data = await fetch(row.data);
    console.log(data);
    row.flag = data;
    dataArray.push(row);
  })
  .on('end', async function () {
    console.log('data', dataArray);
    var result = json2csv(dataArray);
    fs.writeFileSync('./file.csv', result);
  });
```

Comment: The `data` callback is called multiple times, it is called in order but is not awaited in any sense. Load the entire file first, then use Promise.all() to create the array from the data. Your code *does* push to the array, it's just that reading the file is much faster than fetching stuff, so you're logging the still empty array (it's filled after your console.log)

Comment: OK, but for every iteration, I need to fetch the data and store it somewhere. -@ChrisG

Comment: Like I said, just push the row into an array instead, then in the "end" callback, use Promise.all to fetch the data based on the array or rows.

Comment: is fetch [this fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: @Bravo fetch is just for example I am calling an  external API there

Comment: right, because nodejs has `fetch` now, so it looks like you don't know how to use `fetch` :p - I take it the function you ACTUALLY call returns a Promise that resolves to the retrieved data? if it doesn't return a Promise, then awaiting it does nothing useful

Comment: fetch is a custom function I am using internally, that will call an API from there. @Bravo

Comment: and it returns a Promise that resolves to the data you want to fetch? this is important, since `await` waits for a Promise to resolve - any other type of returned value is simply used immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it, First pushed all the row data form on("data" )inside createreadstream into an array "arr". Then as @ChrisG suggested, Created a array called promise and pushed all the promises into the array. And at the end called Promiss.all(promises[]).then I got what I wanted.  @Bravo

```
let arr = [];
let promises = []
  fs.createReadStream(path)
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', async function (row) {
    arr.push(row)
   
 })
  .on('end',  function () {
    console.log("data",arr.length)
    arr.forEach(async e => {
      let msg
      dataArray.push(e)
     
      promises.push(fetch(msg))
     
      }
    })
    Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
            console.log("data",dataArray)   
        data.forEach((e, index) => {
          let data = e.data
          dataArray[index].data = data
        })
         var result = json2csv(dataArray);
         fs.writeFileSync(path, result)
   
    })
    })
   


}
```